# Adding multiple select options with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I've created functionality to move items from the left -> right, and vice versa.  On top of that, I am added the `option` values of each item into a hidden input box, so I can later submit it to the server for processing.  **It seems that when I try to add more than one item at a time, only the first one is being added to the hidden input box though.**

In the end, my hidden input field should look like: `3233,2332,3234,1212,112`

Since I'll accept the parameters in the Ruby on Rails server side to parse and do whatever to (unless there's a better option).

Here's my current code:

```js
$("#btnLeft").click(function(){
    var selectedItem = $("#hosts_assigned option:selected");
    $("#hosts_available").append(selectedItem);
    $("#hosts").remove(selectedItem.val());
});

$("#btnRight").click(function(){
    var selectedItem = $("#hosts_available option:selected");
    $("#hosts_assigned").append(selectedItem);
    var current_hosts = $("#hosts").val();
    $("#hosts").val(current_hosts + "," + selectedItem.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="hosts_available"size="30" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1222">1.1.2.2</option>
    <option value="1232">1.1.2.2</option>
    <option value="1242">1.1.2.2</option>
    <option value="1252">1.1.2.2</option>
  </select>
  
  <select id="hosts_assigned" size="30" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1111">1.1.2.1</option>
  </select>
  
</form>

  <button type="button" id="btnRight">&gt;&gt;</i></button>
  <br/>
  <button type="button" id="btnLeft">&lt;&lt;</i></button>

<br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="hosts" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting more than one.

You need to loop. you also need to loop after removing

```js
function getHosts() {
  var current_hosts=[];
  $("#hosts_assigned option").each(function() {
    current_hosts.push($(this).val());
  });  
  return current_hosts.length>0?current_hosts.join(","):"";
}
$("#btnLeft").click(function() {
  $("#hosts_assigned option:selected").each(function() {
    $("#hosts_available").append(this);
  })
  $("#hosts").val(getHosts());
});

$("#btnRight").click(function() {
  $("#hosts_available option:selected").each(function() {
    $("#hosts_assigned").append(this);
  });  
  $("#hosts").val(getHosts());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="hosts_available" size="30" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1222">1.1.2.2</option>
    <option value="1232">1.1.2.2</option>
    <option value="1242">1.1.2.2</option>
    <option value="1252">1.1.2.2</option>
  </select>

  <select id="hosts_assigned" size="30" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1111">1.1.2.1</option>
  </select>

</form>

<button type="button" id="btnRight">&gt;&gt;</i>
</button>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="btnLeft">&lt;&lt;</i>
</button>

<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="hosts" value="" />
```

Comment: Awesome.  Is the comma that is added to the beginning of the first item going to mess anything up? `,1211,2122,1223`

Comment: See my changes. You forgot to remove the ones when you moved them back. Also when creating the array, make sure there is nothing in the the field